# Loop through column values of table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to PL-SQL . I have a table that contains thousands of records on file information(extract shown below) .I need to compare for 2 files A and B, for thesame task, to check if the task_name is same or different. For example, in the table below, file A task 10 has same task_name (xx) as file B task 10. whereas file A task 20 has a different task_name as file B task 20. I should be able to flag these differences and similarities. I will like to use a cursor within a cursor to loop and compare these values but i don't know how to go about it. I am currently using oracle 11. Thanks

```
File  Task  Task_name 
A     10    xx         
A     20    xy         
A     30    xz         
B     10    xx         
B     20    xz
```

**edit

Thanks for the reply. The reason i needed a loop is because at the end i need to display the results
in a clob variable in the format below. So i need to capture at iteration the task number and task name
to display in the clob variable

-------file comparism-------

Different Task_name

Task 20 : File A Task_name xx vs File B Task_name xz

Task 30 : File A Task_name xz vs File B Task_name NULL

Same Task_name

Task 10 : Task_name xx

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Is a given task (say, 10) supposed to have a consistent task_name (say, 'xx'). If so, then your data model is fundamentally flawed.  Your table should have only FILE and TASK.   Then you'd have a separate 'lookup table' to associate TASK (more properly TASK_ID) with TASK_NAME.

Comment: i edited my question to show output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate by task to get the differences:

```
select
  task,
  max(case when file = 'A' then task_name end) as task_file_a,
  max(case when file = 'B' then task_name end) as task_file_b
from mytable
where file in ('A', 'B')
group by task
having count(*) <> 2 or count(distinct task_name) <> 1
order by task;
```

You can use this inside PL/SQL with a `Cursor FOR LOOP`. Here is the draft:

```
create or replace function get_diff return clob is
  v_clob clob;
begin
  for row in
  (
    select
      task,
      max(case when file = 'A' then task_name end) as task_file_a,
      max(case when file = 'B' then task_name end) as task_file_b,
      case when count(*) <> 2 or count(distinct task_name) <> 1 
        then 'diff'
        else 'same'
      end as diff_same
    from mytable
    where file in ('A', 'B')
    group by task
    order by diff_same, task
  ) loop
    v_clob := v_clob + ...
  end loop;
end;
```

You can access the row data like this: `'Task for file A is' || row.task_file_a`.

You will have to check same / diff, or you simply use two loops one for the differences, one for the equalities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain what this line of code does in your query: 
 having count(*) <> 2 or count(distinct task_name) <> 2

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's wrong. It is supposed to detect a difference. But it must be `having count(*) <> 2 or count(distinct task_name) <> 1`. If for a task you don't find two rows (`count(*) <> 2`, either A or B is missing. If for a task you find more than one task name (`count(distinct task_name) <> 1`) then the the task names for A and B are different. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use PL/SQL but using SQL with `COUNT(..) OVER (..)` analytic function grouped by `Task` and `Task_name` columns through use of `PARTITION BY` clause along with `CASE..WHEN` conditional expression is enough such as

```
SELECT f.*, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT "File") OVER (PARTITION BY Task, Task_name) = 2 THEN
                 'Same'
            ELSE CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT "File") OVER (PARTITION BY Task) = 1 THEN
                 'Unique'
                 ELSE
                 'Different'
                 END
             END AS flag
  FROM files f
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c468f9aa19e6889976fb24e403e06904)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason i needed a loop is because at the end i need to display the results 
in a clob variable in the format below. So i need to capture at iteration the task and task name 
to display in the clob variable

-------file comparism-------

Different Task_name

Task 20 : File A Task_name xx vs File B Task_name xz
Task 30 : File A Task_name xz vs File B Task_name NULL


Same Task_name

Task 10 : Task_name xx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `operator EXISTS`.The EXISTS operator is used with a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

Although in your question there's no mention about duplicate within A/B, you can use universal query to find duplicates within *same group or different*/

Also pay attention to the fact that this query return correct result in the case when *duplicates only within one file group* (for example,just only in A):

```
   --using cte to set row's number
   with cte as
    (
      select *, row_number()over (order by Task,TaskName)num from Table 
    )
    
       select File,Task,TaskName,
       case
       --using t1.num<>t2.num because current row can refer to itself
        when exists (select 1 from cte t1 where t1.Task=t2.Task and 
          t1.Taskname=t2.TaskName and t1.num<>t2.num) 
        then 'Duplicate'
        else 
         'No Duplicate'
        end as flag 
        from cte t2
```

If in your table there's no duplicate within one filegroup and you need to find difference only between A and B file groups then can use this query:

```
           select File,Task,TaskName,
           case
            when exists (select 1 from Table t1 where t1.Task=t2.Task and 
             t1.Taskname=t2.TaskName and t1.File<>t2.File) 
            then 'Duplicate'
            else 
             'No Duplicate'
            end as flag 
            from Table t2
```

You can use `window function count` to count Task, TaskName within file group.But at first you need to remove duplicates within each group and then count values as if there's in one group.
If you need to compare for 2 files A and B then you can try this query:

```
Select File, Task,TaskNane,case when countVal>1 then 'Duplicate' else 'No 
 Duplicate' and as flag
        From
     (
      Select count(*)over (partition by file_gr, Task, TaskName) countVal 
      From
       (
        --add new accessorial column as if there's one group
       Select *,  case when File='B' then 'A' else 'A' end as file_gr
       From
          (
          --remove duplicate within each group A and B
           Select distinct File, Task, TaskName from Table
          ) X
       ) Y
   ) Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (Files,  Task,  Task_name ) as
( 
    select 'A',10,'xx' from dual union all
    select 'A',20,'xy' from dual union all
    select 'A',30,'xz' from dual union all
    select 'B',10,'xx' from dual union all
    select 'B',20,'xz' from dual
)
select  t1.*, nvl((select 'Y' from t t2 where t2.files <> t1.files and t2.task = t1.task and t2.task_name = t1.task_name),'N') as is_same
from    t t1
order   by 1, 2
```

Output:

[image]